# convert 1.5 into 3/2 VB 2008

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a calculator, in which I need to give an option just like CASIO calculators, I mean I want to convert "1.5" into "3/2" or "2.5" into "5/2"

Explanation:

```
Textbox1.Text = 50

Textbox2.Text = 4


Dividing Textbo1.Text and Textbox2.Text
Calculate...........


Textbox3.text = 12.5 (Normaly)
```

but i dont need "12.5"
I want to Convert it into "25/2"

Please Friends Help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take the decimal part, convert to a fraction, reduce the fraction.

Comment: No any calculator gives 50/4 result as 25/2 ... result always in fractional number.

Comment: May want to check this comment on another question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/706644/1001953

Comment: @Rahul ok rahul i accept your point, no one calculator can gives 50/4 result as 25/2, but I need To do this task in VB 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is weird but it's achievable. This might not be the best solution but it can help you - convert this into a function so you can use it later

To make things easier, restrict to (n) decimal place(s) e.g. 1 d.p
For the example you gave above, 50/4 = 12.5

To achieve 25/2 then you'll need this calculations
get the integer part = 12
get the decimap part = 0.5

get the value after(.) = 5
for 1 d.p, divider = 10, for 2 d.p divider=100, so we will use 10
so we have 5/10. You have to check if 10 is divisible by 5 until [No more?] = 1/2
then you have
Your (12 x (bottom) + top) / bottom
= (12x2+1)/2 = 25/2

there could be other alternatives to this steps...

Comment: I thing is Acceptable Answer.. I have Goted A Point. Thanks Tunmise.